# C++ program only prints fixed random numbers/letters to the output.txt file

Tags: c++, debugging, io, output

This is my code, I'm new to C++, whenever I output anything to the output.txt file I only get random numbers/letters regardless of what I try to output [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0lLn.png)

now this problem was not present until I tried to copy a string last night, but back then when I printed the initial string it would get printed normally (as long as I didn't copy the string anywhere else) but this morning when I woke up, every single output to the file would appear to be random numbers/letters, although they are fixed so I'm assuming they are hexa decimal or something, can someone please help me out.

update: output.txt was never closed, I just closed and opened it and everything was back to normal.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the code as text, not an image, as no-one can compile a JPG.

Comment: have you tried to open the file in a different text editor? maybe it is Sublime somehow switched to HEX mode? you can try to reopen the file in UTF-8 encoding with `File -> Reopen with Encoding -> UTF-8` menu option.

Comment: You never close the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets print "hello world" as both characters, and as numbers (in hex format):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string bla = "hello world";
    for (auto c : bla)
        std::cout << c << ' ' << std::hex << +c << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
h 68
e 65
l 6c
l 6c
o 6f
  20
w 77
o 6f
r 72
l 6c
d 64
```

More reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [easier to read table](http://www.asciitable.com/)